# Undefined data when parsing outside async function in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, async-await, dom-events, angular-promise

I have a stuck when I want to parse the data, which get from http call, and parsing it to `ngOnInit`. Can you help me to solve this problem? I am using Angular 4.

the async function :

```
async getAsyncData() {
      this.asyncResult = await this.serviceDashboard.getAllGeografika().toPromise().then(data => {
        return data.length;
      });
      return this.asyncResult;
}
```

`ngOnInit` where I want to print the data:

```
ngOnInit() {
      console.log('Halo from ngOnInit');
      console.log('print data :' +  this.getAsyncData();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not awaiting the promise from your function, so this:

```
 console.log('print data :' +  this.getAsyncData();
```

Is logging the promise, not the resolved value of the promise

You can resolve this in at least three ways:

#### 1. Use async/await

```js
async ngOnInit() {
  console.log('Halo from ngOnInit');
  const data = await this.getAsyncData();
  console.log('print data :' + data);
}

async getAsyncData() {
  const data = await this.serviceDashboard.getAllGeografika().toPromise();
  return data.length;
}
```

This *kind of* breaks the contract of `OnInit`, but you can get away with it.

#### 2. Resolve the promise

This is probably a purer form than the last, but you may not like how verbose it is.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  console.log('Halo from ngOnInit');
  this.getAsyncData().then(data => {
      console.log('print data :' + data);
  });
}

async getAsyncData() {
  const data = await this.serviceDashboard.getAllGeografika().toPromise();
  return data.length;
}
```

#### 3. Use RxJS

My preferred option.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  console.log('Halo from ngOnInit');
  this.getAsyncData().subscribe(data => {
      console.log('print data :' +  data.length);
  });
}

getAsyncData(): Observable<any> {
  return this.serviceDashboard.getAllGeografika();
}
```

Comment: It works, but when i parse it to my chart in html, why they show a blank without the data.                                                                                    async ngOnInit() { 
  console.log('Halo from ngOnInit');
  const data = await this.getAsyncData();
       this.emailChartType = ChartType.Pie;
      this.emailChartData = {
        series: [data, data, data]
      };                                                   
}

Comment: That sounds like an unrelated question.

Comment: I've just realised that `getAsyncData` should also be amended. I've edited my answer.

Comment: In number 1 answer. it shows error ``Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Observable<Koleksi[]>'.``

Comment: So you're trying to await an observable?

Comment: I see you were converting to a promise first. I'll amend my answer